# Why isn't my border image property working how I want it to?

Tags: html, css

I want a border for my entire page on the left and right sides but whenever i try to set the border image it just comes up white, I can change the color without a problem but I want it to be a certain png image only on the left and right sides of the page.

I have already tried all of the border image properties and i have set the border left and right to transparent. I have tried changing my file path too but I know that isn't the issue because I have the same image placed elsewhere.

[Image Of Webpage Borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S9vR.jpg)

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zClUQ.png)

```
<div id="margins">
ENTIRE BODY OF PAGE HERE WOULD BE HERE
   </div>
```

```
#margins {
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-image-source: url('/images/background.png');
```

I need the image to show only in the borders but it isn't showing at all and instead it is showing white.

Comment: Hi Jordan, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide a screenshot of what you are seeing? That would be helpful in troubleshooting. Also, what browser are you using? Are you loading your page from a server or your local filesystem? Depending on your browser, open up your developer tools (For example, in Chrome right-click the page and choose Inspect), then navigate to the Network tab - is the image you are loading failing to load? The `/` before `/images` looks suspect.

Comment: Hello Danny! Thanks for the reply, I have updated my post to include a screenshot. I am using Chrome and I have used the inspect tool and no errors on that specific image. I can ctrl+cmnd to follow the image path is VSC but nothing is showing in the local filesystem. I am not running it on a server, just locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set a border-image-slice and/or border-image-width, and a border-image-repeat property. Note, border-image-width and border-width are different.

```css
#margins {
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300') 50 round;
}
```

```html
<div id="margins">
  ENTIRE BODY OF PAGE HERE WOULD BE HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Jason, I tried that but no luck. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Prove it doesn't work... :) I mean, provide a minimal, runnable example that shows your issue so we can help. This snippet works here using the code you provided to start with. Does it work with a lorem picsum image instead of the local one?

Comment: You are right. I tried it with the picsum image and it worked fine. Does that mean that there is something wrong with the file path of my local image?

Comment: Sorry I am still getting the hang of all of this. Is there a way to make the background image of the whole page to where it flows with the borders? Or would I have to do that separately? So I want the whole background of the page the same image, but I would want the border image to flow with the background image if that makes sense..

Comment: Yep. I'm guessing you have your css file in a css folder at the same level in your directory structure as your images folder. In that case, I think you would need `url('../images/background.png)`

Comment: Jordan, I think I'd need a sketch to understand the "flow with" part...

Comment: I have tried just about every path that I can and still no luck with that image. And I also have added a sketch link to my original post. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Gotcha fam. No need for the image border. Set the body to use the background image and the just position your other elements with a little margin to let the image peek through. I'll add a new answer as an example. Maybe this way will be easier to test the image path too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses a background image on the body that can be seen in the margins around other elements. You can set the image to tile, or use a fixed, centered background with background-size cover for a nice effect.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 50px 20px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300') repeat center;
}

header {
 background: white;
 min-height: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

main {
 background: white;
 min-height: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}


footer {
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>Nav</header>
<main>Content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Exactly what I wanted overall. Only downside was I lost quality when I chose the background-size as cover because when it was on repeat it didn't look right. Will I just have to make the image bigger or how would I fix that issue? You've been a ton of help, thanks a ton.

Comment: If you set background attachment to fixed the image will only  be as large as the device screen. The header and content will scroll but the background will not. Whether this works well or not depends on your image. Just esizing the image isn't a great solution for most content pages because you can't really predict the user's screen size and the length of the content might change drastically.